# Preferences dynamically filled mixed with xml

Tags: android, android-widget, android-preferences

I have a preference activity that loads this resource:

```
<PreferenceScreen>

<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="@string/venues"
    android:key="venues_category">

    <PreferenceScreen
        android:title="@string/venues"
        android:summary="@string/selectToFilter">
    </PreferenceScreen>
</PreferenceCategory>
<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="@string/network"
    android:key="network_category">

    <ListPreference
        android:key="updates_interval"
        android:title="Updates interval"
        android:summary="Define how often updates will be performed"
        android:defaultValue="1000"
        android:entries="@array/updateInterval"
        android:entryValues="@array/updateIntervalValues" />

</PreferenceCategory>
```

The first preference category has a new `Preference Screen` inside, but it has to be filled dynamically. How can I do that? How can I refer to that preference screen and where?

Answer (score 0):

Why is there a PreferenceScreen Inside a Category?
You can create Preferences dynamically
Refer to this sample code
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/preference/PreferencesFromCode.html

Comment: I wanted this to create a new Preference Screen when clicking on it.... But well.. not that isn't what I want

Comment: Is there anyway to reference a listPreference and fill it dinamically?